# Android: Adding header to dynamic listView

Tags: android, listview, listadapter

I'm still pretty new to android coding, and trying to figure things out. I'm creating a listview dynamically as shown below (and then disabling items dynamically also) - you'll notice that there's no xml file for the activity itself, just for the listitem.

What I'd like to do is add a static header to the page. Could someone explain to me how I can modify the code below to EITHER add this programatically within the java file, before the listView, OR edit the code below so that it targets a listView within an xml file!

Help would be much appreciated!!!

```
public class Start extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(null);
      myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);

      try {
     myDbHelper.openDataBase();
  }catch(SQLException sqle){
     throw sqle;
  }

      ArrayList<String> categoryList = new ArrayList<String>();

      Cursor cur = myDbHelper.getAllCategories();
        cur.moveToFirst();
        while (cur.isAfterLast() == false) {

                if (!categoryList.contains(cur.getString(1))) {
                    categoryList.add(cur.getString(1));
                }

                cur.moveToNext();
            }
        cur.close();
        Collections.sort(categoryList);

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listitem, categoryList) {

          @Override
          public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
              View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

              if(Arrays.asList(checkArray3).contains(String.valueOf(position))){
                  view.setEnabled(false);
              } else {
                  view.setEnabled(true);                      
              }

              return view;
          }                 

       });


    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        if(v.isEnabled()) {
            String clickedCat = l.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            Toast.makeText(this, clickedCat, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            finish();
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Questions.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("passedCategory", clickedCat);
            myIntent.putExtra("startTrigger", "go");
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an additional XML file for your activity where you display your list. It might look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/view"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/homeLogo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:scaleType="fitStart"
            android:src="@drawable/logo" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000">
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

What you have is an XML layout for the activity that displays your listview, and in there you can add a static header. I did the same thing for an app I'm building. From there you reference this XML in the activity you are using. Hope this helps.